# OneDrive Subfolder Icons Keep Resetting

Tags: shell, sync, icons, onedrive, cloud

I'm having a frustrating time with my OneDrive client where, when I customize the shell icons for subfolders inside my cloud drive, it resets the icon to default upon synchronization. As frivolous as it may seem, I like to organize my filesystem using custom shell icons (the image of a document inside a file folder for the Documents folder, ...), and the client syncs my cloud instantly after changing it. Of course, I don't want to pause syncing because I want my stuff to be backed up without constantly switching the sync app on and off each time I add, edit, or delete a file to my cloud. Does anyone have an idea on how to circumvent this problem?

(Perhaps, on a more broad scale, what I'd also like to know is if there is a way to retain file/folder properties to sync between server and local storage via the OneDrive client)

Comment: Icon customization settings are stored in a hidden `desktop.ini` file. Apparently, that specific file isn't uploaded at all, and that's probably why the changes get reverted all the time. A [somewhat related article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933738/en-us) seems to confirm this: "*You can't upload files that have a *.tmp or *.ds_store extension, and you can't upload desktop.ini, thumbs.db, or ehthumbs.db files.*"

Comment: Thank you for the response, @and31415, but my OneDrive account is my own personal cloud account, not a business account. Does the same case hold true for non-Pro subscriptions to OneDrive, where I can't sync my Desktop.INI files?

Comment: Although the article is aimed at the business version, the main sync engine is the same, and the restrictions still apply. If you were to patch the engine library you would be able to upload `desktop.ini`, but the problem is that the file attributes aren't synced; to work properly, `desktop.ini` needs to have the Hidden and System attributes set. Either way, I can't reproduce the issue you're describing unless I change the folder icon, stop syncing it, remove it entirely, and sync it again. What operating system and OneDrive version are you using?

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 with the free 15GB OneDrive plan.

Comment: I have the same plan but I was using the standalone OneDrive client on Windows 7 SP1, which is built-in as of Windows 8.1; that could make some difference. All in all, I don't think there's a solution to the problem. As a workaround you might create some shortcuts pointing to these folders, and customize the shortcut icon rather than the folder one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to do it (programmatically) through Command Prompt.

I created a batch file and placed it on the root directory of my OneDrive. I made the folder whose icon I was trying to modify read-only and the desktop.ini file inside it a hidden system file. Here's a sample of the batch script:

`attrib +r "SomeFolder"
attrib +h +s "SomeFolder\desktop.ini"`

All I had to do then was to schedule it to automatically run at a certain interval using the system Task Scheduler, in case the OneDrive client decided to change the icon back again.

I appreciate your help, @and31415. If you're interested in this as well, I do suggest you give this a try.

This post is based on my findings from http://help.lockergnome.com/windows/change-folder-icon-command-line--ftopict455733.html.